# Javascript check if string contains only certain character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to return true if a given string has only a certain character but any number of occurrences of that character.
Examples:

```
// checking for 's'
'ssssss' -> true
'sss s'  -> false
'so'     -> false
```

Comment: so you only want to return true if the entire word is made up of the character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="javascript:;" method="post" class="form-inline" id="form">
        <input type="text" id="message" class="input-medium" placeholder="Message" value="Hello, world!" />

        <button type="button" class="btn" data-action="insert">Show</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
   var onloading = (function () {

            $('body').on('click', ':button', function () {
                var a = document.getElementById("message").value;
                var hasS = new RegExp("^[s\s]+$").test(a);
                alert(hasS);
            });

    }());
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/kXLv5/40/

Answer (score 4):

Just check if anything other than space and `"s"` is there and invert the boolean

```
var look = "s";
if(!new RegExp("[^\s" + look + "]").test(str)){
   // valid
}
```

or check if they're the only one which are present with the usage of character class and anchors `^` and `$`

```
var look = "s";
if(new RegExp("^[\s" + look + "]$").test(str)){
   // valid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

first, convert the string into an array using split,

```
const letters ='string'.split('')
```

then, use the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) data structure and pass the array as an argument to the constructer. Set will only have unique values.

```
const unique = new Set(letters)
```

this unique will have only the unique characters, so, when you pass `sss` then this will have only a single `s`.

finally, if the unique array contains only one element, then we can say this string only contains the same letter.

```
if (unique.size === 1) { // the string contains only the same letters
```

Your function should look like this,

```
function isIdentile(string) {
    const letters = string.split('');
    const unique = new Set(letters)
    
    return unique.size === 1 ? true: false;
}
```

Comment: there is a small error: size it's a Set property, not a function. I'll edit it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do it with sssssnake

```
'sss'.split('s').some(s => s) === true
'sssnake'.split('s').some(s => s) === false
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a RegEx:

```js
const allOne = str => /^(.)\1*$/.test(str)
console.log(allOne(prompt("input")))
```

Explanation of the RegEx:

```
^(.)\1*$   full RegEx
^          start of line
 (.)       any character, stored in group 1
    \1*    repeat group 1 zero or more times
       $   end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Set` + `Array` for this, additionally checking the `""` empty string edge case:

```
const hasOnlyGivenCharType = (str, char) => {
    const chars = Array.from(new Set(str))
    return !chars.some(c => c !== char) && !!chars.length 
}

console.log(hasOnlyGivenCharType('ssssss', 's')) //  -> true
console.log(hasOnlyGivenCharType('sss s', 's'))  //  -> false
console.log(hasOnlyGivenCharType('so', 's'))     //  -> false
console.log(hasOnlyGivenCharType('', 's'))       //  -> false
```